# CDS Linked Service dynamic json

Tags: parameters, azure-data-factory, cds

For CDS linked services, there is no way (from the UI) to introduce parameters.  But!  Microsoft does give us the handy 'Specify Dynamic conent in Json format' check box in Advanced settings.

Does anyone have an example of converting standard linked service json like this:

```
{
    "name": "cdsCorpPlan",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
    "properties": {
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "CommonDataServiceForApps",
        "typeProperties": {
            "deploymentType": "Online",
            "serviceUri": "https://blahblah-dev.crm.dynamics.com",
            "authenticationType": "AADServicePrincipal",
            "servicePrincipalCredentialType": "ServicePrincipalKey",
            "servicePrincipalId": "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx",
            "encryptedCredential": "ew0KICAiVmVyc2lvbiI6ICIyMDE3LTExLTMwIiwNCiAgIlByb3RlY3Rpb25Nb2RlIjogIktleSIsDQogICJTZWNyZXRDb250ZW50VHlwZSI6ICJQbGFpbnRleHQiLA0KICAiQ3JlZGVudGlhbElkIjogIkFERi1MUC1PUkNIRVNUUkFUT1ItREVWX2M0MDYzYjEzLTBkNjYtNDQ2Yi04NjFkLTYyYjJkNjI1MjNlYiINCn0="
        }
    }
}
```

into a paramiterized version?

Specifically, what would be the syntax if I wanted to parameterize the **serviceUri** and **service principal key**?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  For those of you who are interested:

```
{
    "name": "cdsCorpPlanTCO",
    "properties": {
        "parameters": {
            "SecretName": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "type": "CommonDataServiceForApps",
        "typeProperties": {
            "deploymentType": "Online",
            "serviceUri": {
                "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
                "store": {
                    "referenceName": "MyKeyVault",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                },
                "secretName": {
                    "value": "@linkedService().SecretName",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            },
            "authenticationType": "AADServicePrincipal",
            "servicePrincipalCredentialType": "ServicePrincipalKey",
            "servicePrincipalId": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx",
            "servicePrincipalCredential": {
                "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
                "store": {
                    "referenceName": "MyKeyVault",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                },
                "secretName": "SPkey"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices"
}
```